# Trying to set up Catch-All Email Address with Sendmail

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, sendmail

I'm trying to create a catchall email address with Sendmail (it will be used to catch email bounces for [Oceth's OEMPro](http://octeth.com/)).

First I started by creating a new user:

```
# useradd -s /bin/false bounces
# passwd bounces
```

Then I created & opened a virtusertable file with `vim virtusertable` and added:

```
bounces@sub.example.com bounces
@sub.example.com    bounces@sub.example.com
```

Then I added the below line to *sendmail.mc* near the end but before the MAILER_DEFINITIONS of with

```
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
```

Finally, I ran

```
# make
Updating databases ...
Reading configuration from /etc/mail/sendmail.conf.
Validating configuration.
Creating /etc/mail/databases...
Updating auth ...
sasl2-bin not installed, not configuring sendmail support.

To enable sendmail SASL2 support at a later date, invoke "/usr/share/sendmail/update_auth"

Creating /etc/mail/relay-domains
# Optional file...
Updating Makefile ...
Reading configuration from /etc/mail/sendmail.conf.
Validating configuration.
Creating /etc/mail/Makefile...
Updating sendmail.cf ...
The following file(s) have changed:
  /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
** ** You should issue `/etc/init.d/sendmail reload` ** **
# service sendmail reload
 * Reloading Mail Transport Agent (MTA) sendmail                                                                                                                           [ OK ] 
# service sendmail restart
 * Restarting Mail Transport Agent (MTA) sendmail                                                                                                                          [ OK ]
```

After all this it does not seem to be working, how can I test this properly.  I've tried sending an email to bounces@sub.example.com but when I look in */var/mail/* I don't see the *bounces* user.

```
# ls /var/mail/
root  www-data  other-user
```

I created a MX DNS record for this too, e.g. sub.example.com.

The other indication it is not working correctly is that we are getting a 504 error when we try to use this email address as our POP3 Monitoring method in [Oceth's OEMPro](http://octeth.com/).
[image]

### UPDATE

I tried running the below commands as root, in an attempt to debug the issue but I'm not clear what it's telling me.

```
root:/# sendmail -d60.5 -bv no-such-user@sub.example.com
map_lookup(dequote, other-user, %0=other-user) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(host, sub.example.com, %0=sub.example.com) => sub.example.com. (0)
no-such-user@sub.example.com... deliverable: mailer esmtp, host sub.example.com., user no-such-user@sub.example.com
root:/# sendmail -d60.5 -bv bounces@sub.example.com
map_lookup(dequote, other-user, %0=other-user) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(host, sub.example.com, %0=sub.example.com) => sub.example.com. (0)
bounces@sub.example.com... deliverable: mailer esmtp, host sub.example.com., user bounces@sub.example.com
```

I'm not sure why it first tries to look up another user on our system called `other-user`

### UPDATE 2

After running `# echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt` I get the following result.

```
# echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> localhost
ip-1??-??-??-??5
[1??.??.??.??5]
ip-1??-??-??-??5.ec2.internal
[127.0.0.1]
ip-172-31-31-167.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

In *sendmail.mc* I've changed `FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl`  to `FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl`, basically I just removed the `-o` flag.

Then I updated */etc/mail/local-host-names* to include `sub.example.com`, so now it reads:

```
localhost
ip-17?-??-??-?67.eu-west-1.compute.internal
sub.example.com
```

Then I ran:

```
# service sendmail restart
 * Restarting Mail Transport Agent (MTA) sendmail 
# echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> localhost
ip-1??-??-??-??5
[1??.??.??.??5]
ip-1??-??-??-??5.ec2.internal
[127.0.0.1]
sub.example.com
ip-17?-??-??-?67.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

After sending an email to bunces@sub.example.com I still don't see the mailbox in */var/mail/*

```
# ls /var/mail/
root  www-data  other-user
```

I also still get the 504 error in the OEMPro app when I try to configure it with these settings.

Comment: Mailbox file (in `/var/mail`) is created by first delivered email.

Comment: As root execute the following test command: `sendmail -d60.5 -bv no-such-user@sub.example.com`. It should show where sendmail would deliver emails with map lookups tracking (including tracking virtusertable lookups). It should help to narrow pretty long list of possible problems.

Comment: @Andrzej A. Filip thanks, I tried that and updated the question.  Not sure what it's telling me though.

Comment: Could you include link to results produced by the following command executed by root? `echo '3,0 xxx@sub.example.com' | sendmail -d21.12 -d60.5 -bt` [-d60.5 tracking map lookups, -d21.12 tracking processing of `R` lines in sendmail.cf]  It should give 95% chance to locate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sendmail consults virtusertable only for deliveries to local email domains (listed in `$=w`) and virtual domains (listed in `$={VirtHost}`).  It seems that `sub.example.com` is not listed in any of them.

You can add `sub.example.com` to list of local email domains by listing it in file `/etc/mail/local-host-names` (one domain/name per line).  After modifying the file restart sendmail daemon **or** send `HUP` signal to sendmail daemon.

You can check content of `$=w` by executing the following command as root:
`echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt`

Sendmail by default automagically adds some "guesswork" to `$=w`.

---

**Extra hint**:
Do not use `-o` (optional) flag in `FEATURE(virtusertable)`.  Without the flag sendmail refuses to start when compiled version of virtusertable is unawailable.

Comment: thanks but I'm still having the same issues.  I updated my question with the results of what you suggested.  Also should `/etc/mail/virtusertable` have the file extension `.db`

Comment: also when I run `sudo lsof -i :25` it shows that sendmail is using `localhost:smtp (LISTEN)` `sudo lsof -i :25
   COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
   sendmail- 15993 root    4u  IPv4 2035477      0t0  TCP localhost:smtp (LISTEN)`